# array of vehicles

Tags: java, arrays

is there anyone that can help me with java program I spent hour troubleshooting?
 I have no problem reading the file into a string array but I don't seem to know how to use switch or maybe if statement to store each line in an Array of Objects.

> Write an application with a main that reads a file (from the command line) and fills an array of type vehicle[] with new vehicle (params), new car (params), new american car (params) new foreign car(params) , new truck (params), new bicycle (params), etc. depending on the first line that identifies each record.
>   sample of data:
>
> vehicle
>   eRob
>   Rob's house
>   (987) 654-3210
>   Frob@rob.com
>
> truck
>   aDougy
>   Doug's house
>   (123) 456-7890
>   hdoug@doug.com
>   30
>   61234.56
>   8/10/2003
>
> bicycle
>   fTom
>   Tom's house
>   (246) 810-1214
>   Gtom@tom.com
>   7

If you see whats wrong with my code, please point at it:

```
public static void main( String[] args) throws Exception

{ 

  int traceOfArray = 100;

  Vehicle[] vehicle = new Vehicle[traceOfArray];

  File file = null;

  file = new File(args[0]);

  FileReader Fr = new FileReader(file); //read file.

  BufferedReader Br = new BufferedReader(Fr);

  String read = Br.readLine();

  try
  {

      while (read != null) 
      {

      char x = read.charAt(0);

      if(x=='v')

           vehicle[0] = new Vehicle(Br.readLine(), Br.readLine(), Br.readLine(), Br.readLine());

      else if(x=='c')

           vehicle[1] = new Car(Br.readLine(), Br.readLine(), Br.readLine(), Br.readLine(), Br.readLine(), Br.readLine());

     ...
```

Comment: Please reformat your code by highlighting the code block and clicking the button with '1's and '0's.

Comment: Sounds like homework. If so, can you tag it as such?

Comment: Does your code even compile?  It'd be easier to tell what's going on with a complete example

Comment: Check out `ArrayList.add`: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add(int, java.lang.Object)

Comment: I have everything written so far but this part is where I am having trouble with.I am confused with what he wants me to do as well...

Comment: am so new to this site and I guess to java as well :( . I have noone to help me with this, and I know its a little thing thats bugging me here.

Comment: it compiles without this switch statement. how can I do what I am asked without switch statement?

Comment: funny, I've never seen a `default` without a `break`.

Answer (score 2):

One thing is that ArrayLists are different than arrays.

```
arrayList(i++) = new vehicle (Br.readLine(), Br.readLine(), Br.readLine(),  Br.readLine());
```

should probably be

```
arrayList.add(new vehicle (Br.readLine(), Br.readLine(), Br.readLine(),  Br.readLine()));
```

If arrayList really is a `vehicle[]`, then you need to use square brackets, not parenthesis:

```
arrayList[i++] = new vehicle (Br.readLine(), Br.readLine(), Br.readLine(),  Br.readLine());
```

Also, it's customary for class names to start with a capital letter (*Vehicle*, not *vehicle*)

Comment: ok none of this is working. i never worked with arrayList-s before. should I use if statement. should be less complicated than this switch statement

Comment: "not working" is pretty vague.  What part isn't working?  And how is your `arrayList` variable defined?  Is it `ArrayList<vehicle> arrayList = new ArrayList<vehicle>()`, `vehicle[] arrayList = new vehicle[10]`, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

You could also instead just give the BR object as argument to the class and let it figure out how many rows it needs:

e.g.

```
case 'v':
    new vehicle (Br)
```

...